# Bash scripting and rsync: how to include just some folders and subfolders and what happends if I use ../ as path with --delete

Tags: shell-script, scripting, rsync

I have a bash script where I'm trying to copy some folders and archives in local with rsync. I have something like this:

```
RootFolder
  A
  B
  C 
  D
     D1
     D2
     D3
     .
     .
     .
     DN 
  E 
  F
```

What I want/do:

- Clean the Destiny Folder before start which I do with option `--delete`
- Exclude some type of archives which I do with option `--exclude`.
- Exclude some folders which I do with option `--exclude`.

So until here I will have a copy Folders A, B, D and E.

But now I need to copy Only some subfolders in D and the list will change according to a list.

So Imagine I want:

```
 A 
 B 
 D 
   D2 
   D4
   D8
 E
```

I don't know how to do it as I've tried with `--include` but I'm doing something wrong.

I'm doing something like:

```
 rsync -av --delete --include=/D/D2 --include=/D/D4 --include=D8 --exclude=/C --exclude=/F RootFolder/ DestinyFolder
```

But It doesn't work well..... I've thought about doing some iterations or maybe I don't know if I could put all thee includes in a variable and pass it to rsync.

I have another doubt which is: As I get the destination Folder by param, what happens if the user uses "../" and I have the --delete option?? Will it delete the current folder? And if user just writes "/" will it delete everything?

**Edit:**
Having:

```
RootFolder
  A
     File.txt
     .HidenFile
  B
  C 
  D
     D1
     D2
       File.txt
       .HidenFile
     D3
     .
     .
     .
     DN 
  E 
  F
```

I have something like

```
rsync -av --delete  --include=/D/D2 --include=/D/D4 --include=D8 --exclude=*.txt  --exclude=.* --exclude=/C --exclude=/F RootFolder/ DestinyFolder
```

Comment: As for your last paragraph: always check your variables before you use them, especially if you get them from user input. And quote them whenever applicable.

Comment: @WeijunZhou thank you! what do you mean by quoting?

Comment: `"$var"` vs `$var`. One of my favorite questions: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/259023)

Comment: Your latest edit shows that you want to exclude files matching `*.txt` and `.*`. But there are no other files in your example left to copy. Which ones do you really want, and which do you want to ignore? Please make this an explicit statement in your question (use words, not code, to describe the requirement).

Answer (score 2):

The options for `--include` and `--exclude` are applied from left to right. The first options are always the strongest, so you can end a list with `--exclude='*/'` to stop any further processing of directories.

Once you use `--exclude='*/'` though, you will disable implicit processing of all files and directories, and you will need to state explicitly which files and folders to include.

- You want to include `A`, `B`, and `E` with *all their files and folders*,
- You want `D` and its files but not directories,
- You want `D/D2`, `D/D4`, `/D/D8` and *all their files and folders*,
- Nothing else.

We can therefore construct the include/exclude statements like this

```
rsync --dry-run -av --delete

    --include '/A' --include '/A/**'
    --include '/B' --include '/B/**'
    --include '/E' --include '/E/**'

    --include '/D'

    --include '/D/D2' --include '/D/D2/**'
    --include '/D/D4' --include '/D/D4/**'
    --include '/D/D8' --include '/D/D8/**'

    -exclude '*/'

    src/ dst/
```

Since you are using `bash`, which is a shell that can handle arrays, you can build up the set of `--include` instructions safely. Here's an example:

```
# It's an array
includes=()

# Start with the fixed set of known directories
for known in A B E
do
    includes+=('--include' "/$known" '--include' "/$known/**")
done

# Special case
includes+=('--include' '/D')

# Now the changeable set of subdirectories. You might get this list elsewhere
for subdirs in D2 D4 D8
do
    includes+=('--include' "/D/$subdir" '--include' "/D/$subdir/**")
done

# Put it all together
rsync --dry-run -av "${includes[@]}" --exclude '*/' src/ dst/
```

Comment: Thanks. What happends if I have `/A/file.txt` and I have an --exclude=*.txt ? Will work still with your `--include '/A' --include '/A/**'` ? I'll edit my post to add this info and make it clear. And yes, its a bash script

Comment: @Megasa3 why not try it? The `--dry-run` option that I've included in all my examples shows what would happen without actually making any changes.

Comment: Oh! So so sorry I didn't noticed.. I've made my edit but I'm going to try this now. Thanks!

Comment: It starts printing all that is supossed to move like `/A  /.hidenFile1    /.hidenFile2   /.hidenFileN` but just do it with A Folder and if I look into destination, there is nothing.. The /src and/dst are correct as I'm using the same as with my example.

Comment: Remember that `--dry-run` _doesn't actually do any work_. It only shows you what would happen. When you're happy with what it intends to do, just remove that option.

Comment: -.-'' that's right and it's normal that there is nothing on destination haha.  Still... dunno why your code doesn't work... it just copies de /A Folder.

Comment: I tested it with your exact example. It copied exactly what you (originally) said you wanted.

Comment: And again you are right...  i had so many junk in hiden files that it couldn't print everything. solved with a `--exclude=.*`